# How to run darktable-cli in parallel?

Tags: python

I have a sequence of about 1000 CR2 images which I need to convert to TIFF16. The following command line works:

```
darktable-cli input_image.CR2 colorcard.xmp output.tiff --core --conf plugins/imageio/format/tiff/bpp=16
```

But when I want to execute that command in parallel via the Python code below, I am getting the following error after one image is converted:

```
[init] the database lock file contains a pid that seems to be alive in your system: 31531
[init] database is locked, probably another process is already using it
ERROR: can't acquire database lock, aborting.
```

Here is my Python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import glob
import shlex
import subprocess
import multiprocessing as mp

from multiprocessing import Pool


def call_proc(cmd):
    subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


app = '/Applications/darktable.app/Contents/MacOS/darktable-cli '
xmp = ' colorcard.xmp '
opt = ' --core --conf plugins/imageio/format/tiff/bpp=16 --conf plugins/imageio/storage/disk/overwrite=true  --library /tmp/darktable.db'

raw_images = glob.glob('indata/*')

procs = []
for raw_image in raw_images:
    tif_image = raw_image.replace('.CR2', '.tif').replace('indata', 'outdata')
    cmd = app + raw_image + xmp + tif_image + opt
    procs.append(cmd)

pool = Pool(mp.cpu_count())
pool.map(call_proc, procs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Platform:**

- Darktable Version: darktable-cli 3.0.0
- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.3 (18D42)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX 2048 MB

I found the following [thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105969/darktable-cli-fails-because-of-locked-database-file) but had no luck with the given solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the [thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105969/darktable-cli-fails-because-of-locked-database-file), @miguev gave the answer which help me. Which is not pretty but works. I am adding for each image a `tmp` directory and pass that to the `--configdir` attr like so:

```
for i in raw_images:
    os.mkdir('/tmp/' + str(os.path.basename(i).split('.')[0]))

cmds_list = []
for raw_image in raw_images:
    tif_image = raw_image.replace('.CR2', '.tif').replace('indata', 'outdata')
    cmd = app + raw_image + ' ' + xmp + ' ' + tif_image + opt + ' --configdir /tmp/' + str(os.path.basename(raw_image).split('.')[0])
    cmds_list.append(cmd)
```

All you need to do at the end when you are done clean up behind you.